# Random 400 Bad Request (from service worker) error in Angular 10 app

Tags: angular, nginx, cloud-foundry, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular 10 application hosted in PCF. NGINX is used as a reverse proxy with SSL & DNS implemented.

Our website has almost 3k+ users daily but everyday around 20-30 users complain about a blank page error

Note: This is happening mostly in Chrome and I tried disabling service worker from my code without success. It occurs randomly and once the browser cache is cleared the website starts working fine. I am unable to reproduce the issue in my system.

**Error message**:

[image]

**Network**: [image]

**Console**: [image]

This is the request header for which 400 Bad Request (from Service worker) is thrown

**Request URL**

```
https://xxx.xxx.com/search
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 400 Bad Request (from service worker)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 620
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 04:46:34 GMT
Server: Tengine/2.1.0
```

**Request Headers**

```
Provisional headers are shown
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36
```

**My NGINX config looks like this :**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /u01/enginex_1/logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/json;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    upstream ui_page{
        server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx1;
        server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx2;
    }
    server {
        listen       xxx1;
        server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        location / {
            set $remaddr $upstream_addr;
            if ($upstream_addr != "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx") {
              set $remaddr xxx.xxx.com;
            }
            proxy_pass https://$remaddr;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            recursive_error_pages on;
            error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 = @handle_redirect;   
        }
        location @handle_redirect {
            set $saved_redirect_location xxx1.xxx.com;
            proxy_pass https://$saved_redirect_location;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            recursive_error_pages on;
            error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 = @handle_redirect_err;
        }
        location @handle_redirect_err {
            try_files $uri $uri/error.html = 404;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       xxx2;
        server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        location / {
            set $remaddr $upstream_addr;
            if ($upstream_addr != "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx") {
              set $remaddr xxx1.xxx.com;
            }
            proxy_pass https://$remaddr;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            recursive_error_pages on;
            error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 = @handle_redirect;   
        }
        location @handle_redirect {
            set $saved_redirect_location xxx.xxx.com;
            proxy_pass https://$saved_redirect_location;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            recursive_error_pages on;
            error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 = @handle_redirect_err;
        }
        location @handle_redirect_err {
            try_files $uri $uri/error.html = 404;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen         yyyy;
        server_name    xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ui_page;
        }
        
    }
    server {
        listen       zzzz ssl;
        server_name   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
        ssl_certificate      /xxxx.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /xxxx.key;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ui_page;
        }
    }
}
```

**ngsw-config.json**

```
  {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/manifest.webmanifest",
                    "/*.css",
                    "/*.js"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": [
                    "/assets/**",
                    "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
                ],
                "urls": ["https://fonts.googleapis.com/**"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**server.js**

```
/*jshint node:true*/
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression');
var app = express();
app.use(compression());
// var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static('.'));
// app.use(serveStatic(express.static('dist')));
// app.use("/*", express.static("index.html"));
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  //Path to your main file
  res.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=Edge');
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
console.log('About to crank up node');
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "ui-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "server to run ui",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-http-header-size=81000 server.js",  
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "chan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include more details on how nginx is configured, any error logs you can get in the server, etc.

Comment: @MarcSances I have added my nginx.conf above. I am not getting any error in the server error log So I am assuming maybe the request only is not going to nginx?

Comment: @soumodippaul by any chance, did you guys figured out this issue? I'm having the same issue and can't figure out where's coming from.

Comment: @FabioPicheli no luck we are just asking the users to clear cache each time they are facing this issue